# How to send picture into Discord Channel

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I need to send picture (screenshot) into Discord channel. I have successfully developed text sending into channel but I do not know how to send a screen.

Here is part of my code:

```
// connection to the Channel
TextChannel channel = api.getTextChannelById(this.channelId);
        if (channel != null) {
            channel.sendMessage(pMessage).queue();
        }

// capture the whole screen
BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture( new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()) );

// Save as JPEG - not necessary
File file = new File("screencapture.jpg");
ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", file);

// CODE for sendPicture (screencapture to the Channel) HERE!!!
// code here
// code here
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [JDA docs](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/entities/MessageChannel.html#sendFile-java.io.File-), to send a file to a channel, you should use the appropriate sendFile RestAction.

There's a range of different send methods you may use, some of which allow you to send a message along with your file.

As an example, to send a file by using a File object:

```
channel.sendFile(new File("path/to/file")).queue();
```

Or, directly with an InputStream (in your case - to avoid writing to disk).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", stream);
channel.sendFile(stream.toByteArray(), "fileName.jpg").queue();
```